# Py Program using Kivy Module

Tags: python-3.x, class, button, kivy, typeerror

Would like to know why I receive

> TypeError: 'ObservableList' object is not callable. When background_color is being called.

as well as this when vsCode.background([]) is removed I feel I'm missing something simple however I can not put my finger on it thank you in advance:

> TypeError: vsOpen() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
    import os
    import sys
    import subprocess
    import webbrowser as browser
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    from colorama import Fore, Style

    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
            vsCode=Button(text="vsCode", size=(45,45))
            vsCode.background_normal = ""
            vsCode.background_color([0,255,255,0.85])
            vsCode.bind(on_press=self.vsOpen)
            return vsCode

        def encryption(self, on):
            iD = Fernet.generate_key()
            cipher = Fernet(iD)
            message = input(b">: ")
            e_message = cipher.encrypt(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
            if len(e_message) != 0:
              if on == 1:
                print(e_message)
              else:
                dcrypt = cipher.decrypt(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
                print(dcrypt)
            else:
                print("Encryption is not working.")

        def mURLs(self):
           for x in range(0, 2):
              url = input(">") 
              if len(url)!=0:
                  browser.open_new_tab(url)
                  print(Fore.BLUE+"Accessing " + url + "..")
              else:
                  print(Fore.RED+">no url was entered..")
                  sys.exit()

        def vsOpen(self):
           try:
             if os.path.isfile(PATHs[0]) == 1:
                x=subprocess.call(PATHs[0])
             else:
                print(Fore.RED+"vsCode was not found"+Style.BRIGHT)
           except TypeError:
                print("Type error has occured at vsOpen")

root = MyApp()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background_color` is not a method to be called, it is a [ListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color). Perhaps you meant to use:

```
vsCode.background_color = [0, 255, 255, 0.85]
```

Also, when you bind a method to a `Button`, that method is called with the `Button` instance as an argument. So, you can correct the second error by just changing your definition of the `vsOpen()` method as:

```
def vsOpen(self, *args):
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John, that helped i was tired when working on this and could not find a proper solution. For anyone else that looks at this question it should be noted when binding the `button` with a module it in a class it should be called with `self.` to avoid a undefined name warning.

Proper use:

```
 vsCode.bind(on_press=self.vsOpen)
```

Improper use for this:

```
vsCode.bind(on_press=self.vsOpen())
```